# Converting Date to String java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: string, date, exception, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert a date to a String but it gives me an *java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException*, and I really don't know why.
My code: 
`

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String tempStartTime =df.format(currentAgenda.getFestivals().get(0).getFestivalBeginTime());
String tempEndTime = df.format(currentAgenda.getFestivals().get(0).getFestivalEndTime());`
```

It gives me these error when I try to run my program:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at AgendaGUI.createAndShowGUIMenuBar(AgendaGUI.java:152)
at AgendaGUI.<init>(AgendaGUI.java:79)
at AgendaGUI$8.run(AgendaGUI.java:706)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The methods getFestivalBeginTime and getFestivalEndTime both return a Date object, So I don't see why this should be wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: getFestivals() returns empty list maybe

Comment: That seemed to be the problem. Thanks a lot!